# Is 'so young' an adverb or an adjective in this lyrics 'dying so young'?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, gerunds, lyrics

I'm listening to a Japanese Anisong's English ver. *Eiyu Fate's Song* (original title: *英雄　運命の詩*) by EGOIST.

There is a part of lyrics like this:

> ''To give up who you are
>
> and live without your faith
>
> is more regrettable than dying
>
> than dying so young.''

I don't consider that *dying so young* is unnatural to me, but I suddenly considered that *so young* here is an adv. or an adj.? Moreover, is *dying* a gerund?

Comment: Compare [this question about "die happy"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/337244/live-happily-and-die-happy-or-live-happy-and-die-happy-or)

Answer (score 0):

The word 'young' can only be used as either an adjective or as a noun, but not as an adverb. There is no difference between:

to be/feel/look/seem young

and "to die young"

All of these verbs collocate with the word "young" and in all of them "young" is an adjective.

Comment: Are you saying that "dying" is a noun?

Comment: If you are saying that "dying" is a noun, you are wrong. It's a verb.

Comment: @BillJ No, I consider it to be a verb. I just checked the definition of gerunds and it appears that gerunds can only function as nouns, so I omitted the latter part of my post. Thank you.

Comment: “more regrettable than dying” uses “dying” as a gerund, a participle acting as a noun. “Young” modifies “dying” and so is acting as an adjective.

Comment: ***Dying** young is **a** tragedy.* Looks pretty "nouny" to me. But as ever, if there's room for debate about *Which "part of speech" label applies here?*, most likely the categorisation isn't useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> *dying so young*

"Dying" is a verb and "young" is an adjective.

This is a comparative clause functioning as complement of "than" in which "dying" is a gerund-participle verb and "so young" is an adjective phrase functioning as depictive predicative complement (of "dying").