# "live happily and die happy" or "live happy and die happy" or

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I see people say "live **happily** and die **happy**" or ""live/die **happy**" or "live/die **happily**". I even saw this book titled "[Die Happy: A way to Live Happy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9385818317)"

So that makes me believe all of them can work. **Die/live** can be either a linking verb or an action verb here.

But is that the case? Which one (combination) is the most common one?

[image: die happy]

Comment: The words "It's all about convincing self," together with the large number of typos in the book's Amazon description, do not inspire confidence.

Comment: Yes, they're all grammatically valid, but for the sake of parallelism I'd recommend not mixing "happy" with "happily" (unless you have a particular reason to do so).

Comment: Almost all of them work.  I think *die happily* is the only one that doesn't quite fit.  *Die happily* suggest that the deceased was *happy to have died*, not that the deceased was *happy when they died*.  One who *dies happily* is not happy before they die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Happy" is an adjective, and describes *the person* who lives/dies. "Happily" is an adverb, and describes *the way* the person lives or dies.

So, "Live happy" roughly means "Be happy", and "Live happily" roughly means "Live in a way that makes you happy" or "Be happy about living". There's hardly any real difference between those two. "Live happily" is the more natural of the two.

Since death is an instant event, rather than something continuous like living, "Die happy" means "Be happy at the moment of your death", and "Die happily" means "Be happy about the fact you're going to die". These have very different meanings.